# Electric circuit model ODE leads to ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type)

Tags: ode

I am trying to numerically solve the following ODE's of an electric circuit which models the battery of a vehicle:

$\dot{u_{1}} = \frac{-u_{1}}{R_1C_1}+\frac{I(t)}{C_{1}}$

$\dot{u_{2}} = \frac{-u_{2}}{R_2C_2}+\frac{I(t)}{C_{2}}$

$\dot{SoC} = \frac{-I(t)}{Q_{n}}$

In my case, the current $I(t)$ is computed based on a power $P(t)$ that has no analytical form and can be also considered an input to the system of equations. This yields to last two equations:

$I(t) = \frac{P(t)}{V_{batt}}$

$V_{batt} = V_{ocv}(SoC) -R_0I(t) -V_1 - V_2$

Where $V_{ocv}(SoC)$ is obtained through a look-up table.

The first challenge of the problem was to find a way to pass $P(t)$ to the solver. To do so, I defined a class "battery" with $P(t)$ as an attribute and my ode is:

```
def soc_ode(self,state,t):
      
    v1 = state[0]
    v2 = state [1]
    soc = state[2]

    C1 = self.Cs
    R1 = self.Rs
    R2 = self.Rl
    R0 = self.R0
    C2 = self.Cl
    Q = self.qmax*3600
    
    index_t = int(np.round(t/self.dt)) # getting the index of P(t) closer to current t
    i = self.power[index_t]/self.v_bat_old # approximates I(t) using the last V_batt
    v_soc = self.SoC_OCV_curve(soc) # the look-up table I just mentioned

    v_bat = v_soc -R0*i -v1 -v2
    self.v_bat_old = v_bat

    dv1dt = -v1/(R1*C1) + i/C1
    dv2dt = -v2/(R2*C2) + i/C2
    dsocsdt = -i/Q

    d_state = [dv1dt,dv2dt,dsocsdt]

    return d_state
```

It works just fine for some simple $P(t)$ but I get:

'''ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)'''

For several P(t) I'd like to use. One example of P(t) is:
[image]
Perhaps the bug has to do with the spikes in P(t) and some non-differentiability thing, but it also crashes with P(t) = a ramp function:

Is there a better way yo pass P(t) to my ode?
And how can I solve my system with the P(t) in the figure?

Comment: What is the story behind `v_bat_old`, why not use `v_bat`? Note that the implied delay is unpredictable, not necessarily positive, and might oscillate at non-smooth points of the ODE. // "Excess work done" often means that the step size is at some minimum without the solver advancing successfully. Sources can be a singularity or divergence.

Comment: Hi Lutz, I am using the v_bat_old because v_bat(t) depends on I(t) therefore, using the current value would lead to using something referenced before assignement? Do you see a way to solve this issue and use v_bat(t)?

Comment: @PedroDiasLonghitano was thinking what the other poster was until I realized that there must be an interdependence. I’d write the equations with the interdependence then apply your basic solver until you get down to the nonlinear part. At that point you can think about applying Newton or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers! Indeed by solving for the current instead of using an approximation with the last tension value solved the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your system of equation is not of the ODE type.
The variables $u_1$ and $u_2$ have prescribed time variations given by the ODEs you wrote.
The problem is the intensity $I$. The equation you wrote is of the type $I = \frac{P(t)}{A+f(I)} = RHS(I)$, from which you cannot derive an explicit formula for $I$. You circumvent the issue by using the previous value of $I$ for the right-hand side, but this is an extremely bad idea, because your system may not even give the same result if you call it twice in a row with the same input ! This is obviously extremely bad for adaptive integrators.
Actually your system is differential-algebraic (DAE) most likely of index-1 (you may easily find references for that subject). I made a modified version of the Scipy's `solve_ivp` Radau solver somewhere on [GitHub](https://github.com/laurent90git/DAE-Scipy), which is able to integrate such systems.
Alternatively, you can keep the ODE system, but change it so.that at each step you solve iteratively the equation on $I$, either ith a fixed-point method, root solver like `brentq` or a Newton algorithm.

If you need more info, I can update my answer.

Alternatively, you can create a "false" ODE for $I$ which may look like $I = -\frac{1}{\epsilon} (\partial_I RHS)^{-1} RHS(I)$, with a very low $\epsilon$, typically $10^6$. This is analogous to the concept of singular perturbation. Basically, you simply force the intensity to (very) rapidly go back to the set $I-RHS(I)=0$. You then need a stiff ODE integrator like Radau.

Comment: Solving for the current instead of approximating it indeed solved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ! Can you mark this answer as accepted ?